# Display/wrap Woocommerce products in Carousel Slider

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, carousel

I want to display the products via shortcode IE: [product_category category="test" per_page="12"] In a carousel.

I have Flexslider setup, What I have tried is adding this to loop-start.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://googledrive.com/host/0B4TRd-vaKaSkWUFRVkRiM1g2eGs" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://googledrive.com/host/0B4TRd-vaKaSkUHZIaTBXR0JLdVE"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(window).load(function() {
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
                selector : ".products > li",
                animation : "slide",
                controlsContainer : ".flex-container"
            });
});
</script> 

<div class="flexslider">
<ul class="products">
```

and closing the div after ul on loop-end.php

Though I'm not having any luck with it at all :/   It works on a test html file just fine.

The reason I want it like this and not just use some plugin is I have overlay popup that wont work with any Carousel plugin Ive tried and I also want to display multiple categories this way.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I also had this all in the header before with the same result, don't think it likes the way the list items are generated.

Answer (score 1):

Initially I thought your markup didn't match, but then I saw that you've modified the loop. Though I think the jQuery selector `ul.products` would work. Because it should be container and its direct children as slides.

I would advise you to look in your browsers developer console to see what kind of script errors you are getting. But I suspect you are seeing something along the lines of function not defined since you aren't using [no conflict wrappers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers). You have no idea how much this frustrated me in the beginning.

Your script should therefore look something like (though I think you should add it to the footer:

```
function so_28486348_print_footer(){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
          $('ul.products').flexslider({
                    selector : "li.product",
                    animation : "slide",
                    controlsContainer : ".flex-container"
           });
    });
    </script> 
<?php }
add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', 'so_28486348_print_footer
```

I would also advise loading all your scripts (at least the external scripts) via `wp_enqueue_script` (see the codex link above)

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-script', 'https://googledrive.com/host/0B4TRd-vaKaSkUHZIaTBXR0JLdVE' ,
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

Comment: Even I faced that frustration when I was very beginner to wordpress ;)